# Solr multicore issue with locking

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

The issue I have is locking on both indexes.

To explain, when constructing the EmbeddedSolrServer server I have to parse the `CoreContainer` and the core name and so I have constructed two seperate instances of the `EmbeddedSolrServer`, one for each core. Now I essentially do this (example code):

```
serverInstanceOne.add(document);
serverInstanceTwo.add(document) // This fails to obtain a lock
```

1. If serverInstanceOne is purely targeting core1, why does it create a lock in the index of core2?
2. Is there a way to prevent this? Or a way of forcing the server to drop the lock without shutting down each time?

I have tried to find in the Solr documentation an explanation around this behaviour but am at a loss still. Essentially I am using multicore and have a spring batch job, which is using the `EmbeddedSolrServer` to pump data overnight into some indexes.

Comment: Are your server instances in some way connected? E.g. are they replicating?